# How to get data and call api based on another api call's data

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I am trying to call api and, if returns any data then i have to display that data else, i will call another api to get data.

I have service that gets data to me. If there is any data then i will use that data to render html file. However, if there is no data then i have to call another API to get data.

i am calling below function in constructor.

```
this.availableDetailsArray = this.getConstactListBySabhaID(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
```

Above code is calling this function.

```
getAvailableSabhaAttendance(id) {
this.contactService.getAttendanceIfAvailable(id).subscribe(data => {
  let temp = [];
  temp = data.data;
  this.availableSabhaDetails = temp;
 console.log(this.availableSabhaDetails);
});
return this.availableSabhaDetails
```

}

if there is data in above api then i am fine. However, i am not able to get this data to call another api.

second function is returning this:

```
{id: 12, topic_name: "Nishtha", sabha_id: 8, sabha_child_id: 1, speaker_name1: 56, …}
absent_contact: "129"
attendance_id: 10
created_at: "2018-12-27 22:13:31"
id: 12
present_contact: "55,118,122,126,116,58,125,119,132"
sabha_child_id: 1
sabha_date_time: "2018/12/18 - 13:45"
sabha_details: "Video Darshan"
sabha_id: 8
speaker_name1: 56
speaker_name2: 18
topic_name: "Nishtha"
updated_at: "2019-01-13 14:50:42"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: this.contactService.getAttendanceIfAvailable(id).subscribe(data => {
 // inside here why dont you check if data is empty or not and call the 2nd API
});

Answer (score 1):

In the method **getAvailableSabhaAttendance**:

1. you already have a **block (named data)** to handle the data returned, you can include 2 more blocks
2. **error block (named errr below)**: which can handle the error returned from the service method, and if you'd like, call your 'second function'
3. **finally block, (written as () => {} below)**: this is where you can validate the data you received in the first block and in case of validation issues, you can call your 'second function'

```js
    getAvailableSabhaAttendance(id) {
      this.contactService.getAttendanceIfAvailable(id).subscribe(
        data => {
          let temp = [];
          temp = data.data;
          this.availableSabhaDetails = temp;
          console.log(this.availableSabhaDetails);
        }
        ,errr => { /* This is the case of error, you can call the 2nd API here  */}
        ,() => {
          /* This is the case of finally, you can validate the data here and if the validations fail, call the 2nd API here  */
        }
      );
      return this.availableSabhaDetails;
    }
```

Comment: But even if there is no data in first api, it is not returning error to me. Then how do i call 2nd api there without confirming data from 1st call

Comment: If you get no error (errr block wouldn't fire) and if you get blank-data from first API (data block will fire) and you can call the 2nd API in the data block right then and there